# Set the fonts within TikZ to default LaTeX font

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts

I have TikZ code for generating an image. There are also labels in this image. I want the font of these labels to be the default LaTeX font i.e., cmr10. I found out that the font style within TikZ environment can be changed using:

```
\tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily}}}
```

I do not know what `\sffamily` should be replaced with in order to set the font style as cmr10. How can this be done?

Comment: `\rmfamily` or simply just remove that line